# How to force Internet Explorer 11 to display image aspect ratio correctly?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox

If you look at [this page](https://eoy.ee/oosorr/test) with Internet Explorer 11, you can see images aspect ratio is uncorrect - image is vertically stretched. IE 11 stubbornly displays image's original height. All other browsers (latest Chrome, Firefox and Edge versions) displaying correctly. Why this css code not working with IE 11?

html:

```
<section class="content-6 sec-content">
<div class="container sec-right">
<div>
<img src="https://eoy.ee/oosorr/images/8.jpg" alt="Nõmmemännik" width="1280" height="853" />
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

css:

```
img {
width:100%;
height:auto;
max-width: 100%;
}

.sec-content{
display:-ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction:column;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
-ms-flex-pack: end;
justify-content: flex-end;
}

.sec-content > div{
padding-bottom:50px;
display:-ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-ms-flex-direction: row;
flex-direction:row;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.sec-right{
-ms-flex-pack: end;
justify-content: flex-end;
}

.sec-right > div{
display:-ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction:column;
padding:35px 45px;
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
width: 90%;
}

.sec-right > div::before {
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
content:" ";
top:0;
bottom:0;
width:3000px;
position: absolute;
z-index: -100;
}

.sec-right > div::before {
left: 0;
}
```

Comment: IE has some issues with images being flex items and you might be better of wrapping the image. If not, one option is setting `min-height: 1px` on the image, though can't say if that works all the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this discussion](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/issues/75) there seems to be a bug with IE flexbox implementation, that can be worked around with adding the following code to your image css styles:

```
img {
    ...
    min-height: 1px;
}
```

Comment: I searched all day for this answer, THANK YOU!
Btw, my issue seemed isolated to the Windows 10 version of IE11

Answer (score 0):

Piotr link was very useful - `min-height:1px` [solved the problem.](https://eoy.ee/oosorr/oosorr/) it didn't help then i added it to `img`, but to `.sec-content > div`. and i removed flexbox properties a little. final css:

```
.sec-content{
display:-ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction:column;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
-ms-flex-pack: end;
justify-content: flex-end;
}

.sec-content > div{
padding-bottom:50px;
display:-ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-ms-flex-direction: row;
flex-direction:row;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
    min-height: 1px;
}

.sec-right{
-ms-flex-pack: end;
justify-content: flex-end;
}

.sec-right > div{
padding:35px 45px;
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
width: 100%;
}
```