# ASP.NET: Gridview image issue between Internet Explorer and Firefox

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, webforms

I have a gridview on my asp.net webforms page to display pictures:

```
        <div class="col-md-12" style="width: 1265px; height: 1000px; overflow: auto;">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Font-Names="Arial">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IMS-Bilder">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton CssClass="myImage" ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Bild-Pfad")%>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
```

I use the following css to display the images centered with different aspect ratios:

```
        .myImage {
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 75%;
            height: 75%;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 5px;
        }
```

this works with mozilla firefox:
[image]

but not under internet explorer 11:
[image]
the images are stretched massively vertically. did i miss something in the css or are there maybe other hints for the internet explorer? [min-height: 1px](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54054592/12350648) I tried unsuccessfully...

Comment: why do you set the height, if you just want to center them horizontally?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? height: 75%? I do that because the original size is too big. The problem is that pictures are shown as an example in 16:9 format as approx. 3:9 (as can be seen in the screenshot). they are practically stretched in the wrong direction, @Homungus

Answer (score 1):

To make the image centered and keep your aspect ratio just set width only - height doesnt matter in your case, because your are scrolling the container:

```
        .myImage {
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 75%;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 5px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually height and width are in percentage. so according to actual size height and width images vary in browser refer [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dimension.asp) . Make height and width fixed according to need or eliminate it:

```
.myImage {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;    
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
}
```